# Create AppBar as a class flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, appbar

i'm trying to make an appbar as a class for one of my page of my app (only used on 1 page).

I'd like to have **addStoryAppBar** for my code to be easier to read. How do I do this ? I've tried to create a widget, but it remove the leading back icon

```
class StoryAddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StoryAddPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StoryAddPageState createState() => _StoryAddPageState();
}

class _StoryAddPageState extends State<StoryAddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar addStoryAppBar = AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        AppLocalizations.of(context).add_story,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColors.Black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 16),
      ),
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(
        "lib/assets/images/back.svg",
        semanticsLabel: 'Back icon',
        fit: BoxFit.none,
        height: 10,
      ),
      actions: [
        GestureDetector(
          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/select_picture.png'),
          onTap: () => {},
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: kOrangeButton,
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).publier,
                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.Black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: addStoryAppBar,
        body: Container(
          child: Text('Add story'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also tried to extends the AppBar, but how do I pass the context ? Is this the more adapted thing to do ?

```
class StoryAppBar extends AppBar {
  StoryAppBar()
      : super(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, //change your color here
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).add_story,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.Black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
          ],
        );
}
```

Comment: preferred way as I have seen is implementing PrefferedSizeWidget using simple stateless widget. You can directly use the widget as a custom appbar.

Answer (score 2):

if you have stateless widget  you can Easily   implement   PreferredSizeWidget
this example show you how do that :

```
    class CustomAppbar extends StatelessWidget implements 
       PreferredSizeWidget{
          const CustomAppbar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
    
      @override
      Size get preferredSize => Size(15.h, 100.w);
    }
```

if you are using  StatefulWidget you can copy paste this code

```
          class CustomAppbar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
          final bool? isBack;
          final TextEditingController? controller;
        
          const CustomAppbar({Key? key, this.isBack, this.controller})
              : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<CustomAppbar> createState() => _CustomAppbarState();
        
          @override
          Size get preferredSize => Size(15.h, 100.w);
        }
        
        class _CustomAppbarState extends State<CustomAppbar> {
        
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container()
          }
        }
```

and now you can use class on appbar

```
Scaffold(

  appBar: CustomAppbar(

  );
```

the rason for that if you enter to appbar you will see

> /// An app bar to display at the top of the scaffold.   final
> PreferredSizeWidget? appBar;
>
> the app bar is  PreferredSizeWidget  and PreferredSizeWidget implement
> Widget Class  which contain  get method

```
  Size get preferredSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `AppBar` widget to a statefull or stateless widget.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own leading back icon. Just create Text Button, like this:

```
TextButton.icon(
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded),
    label: Text(''),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate method that returns `AppBar` to your screen widget. Add the below method in a new class and call this method from anywhere you want to show `AppBar`

```
AppBar getApplicationAppBar(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text(
      AppLocalizations
          .of(context)
          .add_story,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.Black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          fontSize: 16),
    ),
    leading: SvgPicture.asset(
      "lib/assets/images/back.svg",
      semanticsLabel: 'Back icon',
      fit: BoxFit.none,
      height: 10,
    ),
    actions: [
      GestureDetector(
        child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/select_picture.png'),
        onTap: () => {},
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: kOrangeButton,
          onPressed: () => {},
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              AppLocalizations
                  .of(context)
                  .publier,
              style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.Black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

If back button functionality not works, then use `GestureDetector` on Back Button

```
leading: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context); 
      },
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        "lib/assets/images/back.svg",
        semanticsLabel: 'Back icon',
        fit: BoxFit.none,
        height: 10,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: @lucrece: could you accept the answer if it satisfies your need,